# indexing panels to change their content during runtime

Tags: java, containers

I am working on simple components that I could possibly use in my university assignments next year.

I wanted to create custom panel that would display different information (e.g. track name, description, artwork, button). I managed to create a separate class that creates a panel, that contains other panels that display the information. I want to be able to modify everything in each panel during runtime (e.g. change the title, remove one element). What is the logic behind it and what should I use?

Comment: Very broad question. Probably too broad. However, some peoply might be trigger-happy with pointing to things like [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Are you familar with [Java events handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)?

Comment: I am not understanding why you need a custom class for this.  Panel and JPanel already include all of the capabilities that you are looking for out of the box.  For example, you can create a JLabel with an ImageIcon or text and add it to any panel to display that image/text.  You can always add multiple child components (even other containers) to a container like Panel.  What are you trying to do that the default implementations don't already do?

Comment: yes, this is what I am trying to use. The idea was to create something that would work like a container for list of albums with an "options" button for each album.

Comment: I am trying to create a separate class for that using swing components (JPanel etc.). I am trying to achieve this mainly for learning purposes. I am mainly interested in the logic behind it.

Comment: You can (and probably should) create custom classes for this sort of "structured" information. For example, you could have an `AlbumPanel`, that internally has a `JLabel titleLabel`. When you assign an `Album` to this panel, you can place the title of this album to the label, with something like `titleLabel.setText(album.getTitle());`. But there is not much "logic" behind this, **unless** you want to be notified about modifications in the album. So still, it's not clear what the question is actually aiming at....

Comment: hi guys, i managed to solve my problem using action listener. thanks for your comments